# Roll of deli paper and how it changes

Tags: calculus

I work in a restaurant and one of the closing duties is to rip paper for tables (paper table cloths).  One night I was pulling paper from the end of the roll and had to switch to a new bigger roll.  The heavy roll of paper sits on a cutting contraption where the cutter is on a spring hinge that sits against the cylinder of paper.  We use a piece of string that pulls out from the contraption at a length of 23 inches.  We can assume that the string attaches at the center of the circle.  The length of the string stays the same.

When I changed the paper to the bigger roll I stopped and thought, "Wait a minute, now that I am using a larger roll of paper, the length of the paper being ripped will change because the cutting strip is now further away from the center of the circle."  So I measure the difference between the two cuts and, indeed, there was a two inch difference.  At the beginning of the roll the paper being ripped measures 23 inches and at the end of the roll the paper being ripped measures 25 inches.

As you move through the roll the pull of the paper will turn the cylinder more and more times so the rate the radius decreases will decrease at a faster rate towards the end of the roll.  We start with a 4 in radius cylinder of paper and the cylinder core is 1 3/4 inches in radius.  There is a full 9,700 linear feet of paper in this roll.

What I want to figure out is the equation to show the change each rip of paper will undergo as the circle gets smaller.  And then I want to graph this change.  I have poked around the Archimedes spiral and I am trying to stay away from polar coordinates if possible.

Thanks in advance for any help you can throw my way.  This is driving me crazy!!

Comment: Have you got a photo of it that we could look at to help us imagine what's going on here?

Comment: if you have no photograph, perhaps you can draw two pictures and post them as jpegs here; these would be side views, showing the positions of the string and cutting thing for a large roll, then a diagram for a small roll.

Comment: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81CIHWqAqoL._SL1500_.jpg

Comment: The above is the exact picture of what the cutter looks like.  The string is tied on the leg of the device.  Thanks again for your time with this.

Comment: As you pull each strip of paper you decrease the area of the circle (if you consider the side view of the cylinder).  But the decreasing radius decreases at an increasing rate with each pull of paper because the number of rotations changes as you move through the roll.

Comment: There seem to be too many variables still not specified here. If the string really measures the distance from the axis of the cylinder to the free end of the roll the we would expect the amount of paper unrolled to increase as the radius decreases, but not by as much as you observed. But the amount unrolled is not necessarily the amount cut; it depends on where the cutter is relative to the direction you pull the paper.